# Simple Roots of E6 in Coordinates?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

There are several possibilities how one can write simple roots in terms of coordinates. Firstly, they depend on the numbering of the nodes in the Dynkin diagram. Let's fix the choice for $E_6$ to be

[image: DynkinE6]

Unfortunately there are still several possibilities. For example, this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1994-341-02/S0002-9947-1994-1139491-1/S0002-9947-1994-1139491-1.pdf) quotes at the second page very different simple roots than [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_%28mathematics%29) which claims that the simple roots in coordinates are the rows of the following matrix:

[image]

Which set is correct? Or are both? My problem is that I get very different result if I use these two different sets. Is there some good resource that lists the different possibilities?

Comment: If you apply any rotation to those roots you get another set of vectors that also generates the root system $E_6$. Alternatively you can think of these are representing those vectors using another orthonormal basis. Any set of vectors with the correct pairwise inner products will do as well. So there are infinitely many sets of simple roots of a root system of type $E_6$. There is no way to get rid of this freedom. You need to live with it.

Comment: Anyway, I didn't check but both are probably correct.

Comment: OT as it origins from WP, but: What is the purpose of the colour coding in the Dynken diagram?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot for the clarification. My problem is that I use a software package called LieArt (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6379v2.pdf), which computes weight systems for arbitrary representations. The software displays the weight in the simple root basis (alpha-basis called there). Therefore, the weights written like this must depend on choice of the simple roots, i.e. must change if we perfom a rotation on the simple root basis?! For different simple root choices, the coefficents w.r.t this basis are different. Unfortunately I can't figure out which basis they use.

Comment: That is a non-problem. If you change the basis of the ambient Euclidean space, and consequently the roots become different vectors in $\Bbb{R}^6$, then the weights are changed accordingly. The relation between the roots and the weights does not change. For example with type $A_2$ the fundamental weigts are always $(2\alpha_1+\alpha_2)/3$ and $(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2)/3$. Irrespective of which two plane vectors the simple roots happen to be.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen LieArt lists the weights in the "alpha-basis", i.e. $$w =(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)=a_1 \alpha_1 + a_2 \alpha_2 + a_3 \alpha_3 +\ldots, $$ where $\alpha_i$ denotes the simple roots. Therefore, I think, the coeffiecents $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ depend on the choice of the $\alpha_i$. For example, if we wish to change names $\alpha_1 \leftrightarrow \alpha_2$ the weight changes to $w =(a_2,a_1,a_3,\ldots)$?!

Comment: Ah! So you are only worried about permutations of the simple roots. Yes, then you apply the corresponding permutations to the coordinates of the fundamental weights. I don't have the time to check, but it looks like that Wikipedia-article is giving the $\alpha$:s in terms of some orthonormal basis of $\Bbb{R}^6$. IOW this is an apples & oranges confusion. Gotta go. Talk to you in a bit over 2 hours (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to verify $\langle v,v\rangle = 2$ for all rows $v$ and $\langle v,w\rangle=-1$ precisely for rows joined by a line and $\langle v,w\rangle=0$ otherwise.

Comment: This refers to the WP suggestion; I get a 404 for the paper